# Cosmos .NET SDK Bulk execution without exceeded provisioned throughput

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a NoSQL Cosmos DB Container with manually provisioned throughput.

I have an application that upserts a lot of documents at once using the v3 .NET SDK for cosmos DB with bulk execution mode enabled.

I am having 429 (Too Many Request) errors surfaced to the application level. How can I avoid this?

I am using bulk execution mode because I want to upsert the documents as quickly as possible. But of course I don't want to exceed my manually provisioned throughput. What can I do?

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/process-bulk-data-azure-cosmos-db-sql-api/3-review-bulk-operation-caveats) mentions that max RU consumption increases with bulk execution mode.

Comment: If you reach 429's then you already ARE upserting as quickly as possible with your RU limit. Simplest is to increase RU limit to match you load.

Answer (score 1):

The total RU consumed does not increase, but because you are sending more operations **per second** then the RU **per second** increases, because the goal is to remove the client-side bottleneck and allow you to take advantage of available RU for ingestion.

At the moment there is no way to define an RU limit, you are defining the RU consumption by the size/number of documents you are processing through Bulk, so you can define a number and create subsets of your whole data that are in batches of a number you feel comfortable sending based on your RU usage.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using bulk execution mode because I want to upsert the documents as quickly as possible.

**If you get 429s then you are reaching your goal of "as quickly as possible" for given RU limit.** See [Diagnose and troubleshoot Azure Cosmos DB request rate too large (429) exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-request-rate-too-large?tabs=resource-specific#recommended-solution):

> In general, for a production workload, if you see between 1-5% of requests with 429 responses, and your end to end latency is acceptable, this is a healthy sign that the RU/s are being fully utilized. No action is required.

So, **429s are not necessarily a bad thing** unless you client continues to try to push in too many docs at the same time, overwhelms the RU limit and retry-mechanism completely and 429s turn to failed business operations. Then its a bad sign.

The built-in retry mechanism should be able to avoid hard fails by respecting [the `x-ms-retry-after-ms` header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-response-headers) automatically on retries:

> The number of milliseconds to wait to retry the operation after an initial operation received HTTP status code 429 and was throttled.

As already mentioned by Matias the **key is to help your app avoid piling up too many requests by adding batching to the client and waiting after each batch to catch up with RU limit, before sending in the next pile**. This way auto-retry mechanism keeps on using full RU-limit, business side slows down if waits are needed, and eventually all docs get sent.

Though, increasing RU limit to match you ingestion rate also helps;)